# How to make tar to ignore last-modified-time of files/directories

Tags: tar

I'm using `tar` to backup a directory. Some files/directories' `last-modified-time` will be updated but the content remains.
I would like to get a tarball with the binary if the directory files' content are not modified.

However, as long as the `last-modified-time` updates, the generated tarball's binary differs.

Is there a way to let `tar` ignore `last-modified-time`? So that I can get the same binary as long as the contents are not changed.

Comment: `tar` does not know what the previous date *was*.  If you had a reference, you could devise a script to touch unmodified files to restore their modification dates.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the `mtime` is staying the same, however the content hasn't changed? I can understand the issue if we're talking about `atime`, but not `mtime` since that should only be updated when the file is changed. Are you sure it's `mtime`?

Comment: Tar has to write something in the mtime field of each file's entry in an archive; it's part of the format. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030545/how-to-compare-two-tarballs-content for some programs that will compare two tar archives.

Comment: @PaulCalabro To be more precisely, I'm talking about `mtime` and `ctime`, e.g. `touch <file>` or `chown xxx`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks, but I'm then using rsync to backup the tarball. Do you know if it is possible to backup the dir using a tarball (or whatever archive) and sync it with rsync (or whatever sync) without additional transfer on unmodified contents?

Comment: GNU tar has a `--mtime` option that lets you override the mtime as you add files to an archive. You can also reduce the time it takes rsync to copy the tar archive by placing files whose contents have recently changed at the end of each archive and keep unchanged files together, and in the same order, at the beginning of the archive; rsync copies deltas rather than entire files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you are not only looking for a fixed mtime inside the TAR, but for a bit-for-bit identical tarball given that the files themselves are identical. This is actually more complex than one thinks it is.

Depending on your situation, not all points may be relevant, but I am listing them here for completeness. In GNU tar you can do the following:

- set the mtime using `--mtime=<date>`. From version 1.29 (on Debian 1.28-1 on, you can use `--clamp-mtime` to set the  real mtime of the file only for files /newer/ than the given mtime. This is useful, when you want to give generated files a common timestamp, but leave the other files alone.
- To have a predictable order of files in the archive use `--sort=name` (GNU tar 1.28 or later). The default behaviour is `--sort=none`, which stores files in directory order.
- `--owner=0 --group=0 --numeric-owner` to set the owner (if you are creating the TAR from different users).
- permissions can be different due to a different umask. Use `chmod` before the creation of the archive or use `--mode=<CHANGES>` to change them to be consistent.

The Reproducible Builds initiative has a [good article on generating bit-for-bit identical archives](https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/archives/).

The article also provides some workarounds for older tar versions, which might also work with other TAR implementations. A workaround for the mtime specifically is, that you can use `touch` before creating the TAR to set the mtime to a fixed value for all files newer than a certain date. For a predicable order inside the archive use `find` and `sort` to pass an ordered file-list to TAR.

```
find build -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z
  | tar --no-recursion --null -T - -cf product.tar
```

Refer to the [GNU TAR documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html) and manpage for information on the individual options.